# how to hide minicart content if subtotal is greater than $100000 in magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I am trying to restrict customer cart value to $100000.If customer cart value reach $100000, then i want show one message in minicart and hide proceed to checkout,view cart buttons. Is there any way to achieve that.
please help me.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [visible](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/visible-binding.html) binding of Knockout JS to accomplish that.

You should look for the templates where the "Proceed to Checkout" button is located (and/or any other element that you want to hide), and override it.

Then look for the `subtotal` variable and do something like this in order to make the div visible only if the subtotal is fewer than 100000:

```
<div data-bind="visible: subtotal() < 100000">
```

Hope it helps.